# Showing continuity from above of Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
  is increasing right continuous and we define a pre-measure on the semi-algebra $\mathcal{A}:=\left\{ \left(a,b\right]\ |\ a\leq b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ 
  by $\mu\left(a,b\right]=F\left(b\right)-F\left(a\right)$
 . I have easily shown this is finitely additive and I want to show it is also continuous from above to deduce $\sigma$-additivity. So assume $\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]\in\mathcal{A}$
  is descending to $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]$
 . I distinguish between several cases:

1. If $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$
   and $b_{n+1}<b_{n}$
   for all $n$
   then there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$
   s.t $c\in\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]$
   for all $n$
   and also $a_{n}\uparrow c$
   and $b_{n}\downarrow c$
   . In this case we have $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]=\left\{ c\right\}$ 
   and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_{F}\left(\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(F\left(b_{n}\right)-F\left(a_{n}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(b_{n}\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(a_{n}\right)=F\left(c\right)-F\left(c-\right)$$
2. If $b_{n+1}=b_{n}$
   for all $n\geq N$
   and $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$
   for all $n$
   then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]=\left(c,b_{N}\right]$
   where $c=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$
   and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_{F}\left(\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(F\left(b_{n}\right)-F\left(a_{n}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(b_{n}\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(a_{n}\right)=F\left(b_{N}\right)-F\left(c-\right)$$
3. If $b_{n}<b_{n+1}$
   for all $n$
   and $a_{n+1}=a_{n}$
   for all $n\geq N$
   then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]=\left(a_{N},c\right]$
   where $c=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n}$
   and so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_{F}\left(\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(F\left(b_{n}\right)-F\left(a_{n}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(b_{n}\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(a_{n}\right)=F\left(c\right)-F\left(a_{N}-\right)$$

Since I only know $F$
  is right continuous I'm constantly stuck with those left sided limits which are preventing me from getting the equalities I want. How exactly do I get around this? Am I supposed to somehow use the fact the discontinuities of $F$
  are countable (and of Lebesgue measure zero) and just assume all the points $a_{n},b_{n}$
  are continuity points of $F$
  ?

**Edit**: I obviously had a mistake in the first case, there of course doesn't have to be such $c$ and in fact we have $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n},b_{n}\right]=\left[\sup\left\{ a_{n}\right\} ,\inf\left\{ b_{n}\right\} \right]\notin\mathcal{A}$ which means we can disregard the first case. Similarly in the second case we will also reach a similar contradiction and in general the fact the intersection is in the semi-algebra appears to imply the sequence ${a_{n}}$ must be constant from some place in order for the intersection to be in the semi-algebra. This of course resolves the problem.

Comment: Since left-continuous increasing functions don't induce measures I don't think the solution is assuming all points are continuity points cause I could do the same for left continuous functions and reach a false conclusion.

Comment: In this setting, you assume that the intersection is an element of $\mathcal{A}$. ($\mu(A)$ wouldn't be defined otherwise.) So there are $a\leqslant b$ with $(a,b] = \bigcap (a_n,b_n]$. That has certain consequences for the sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Thanks for replying. In all the cases I mentioned I already knew that this descending union of intervals ends up being either a singleton or a half open interval and I didn't assume anything about the sequence $(a_{n})$. So unfortunately it appears I am missing what is implied about $(a_{n})$ and how it resolves my problem. Could you perhaps help me out by pointing it out?

Comment: You can deduce something about the sequence $(a_n)$ from the shape of the intersection. What is $\bigcap \bigl(-\frac{1}{n},1\bigr]$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It's $[0,1]$ which wouldn't be in the semi-algebra. Does that mean $(a_{n})$ has to be constant from some place? 
Even if it were constant I'm not sure how that rids me of the problem in the case where (a_{n}) is strictly increasing and (b_{n}) is strictly decreasing and I get a singleton as the intersection, isn't the singleton still a member of the semi-algebra?

Comment: Right, $(a_n)$ must be eventually constant, otherwise the intersection would be of the form $[a,b]$.